# App stuck when relauch after press back button on root screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using `React Native 0.57.8` and Wix `React Native Navigation v2.7.1`, and on my root screen when I press the virtual back button of my phone, the app seems to close and goes back on my app launcher. But, when I relauch the app, it get stuck on a black screen forever, until I kill the app and reopen it again.

I'm don't understanding why happens that, is really weird.

I tried with `BackHandler` on the root screen with no success:

```
this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
  BackHandler.exitApp();
  //return true;
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that behaviour with a `Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener` of react-native-navigation on App.js, in order to call `setRoot()`...

```
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
      Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        sideMenu: {
          left: {
            component: {
            ....
            }
          },
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix was:

```
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }
  Navigation.setRoot(myRoot);
}
```